# Short story collection featuring people who don't age except their brains and another story about trials by bullet where a god saves the innocent

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There were a few stories; one of them was about a society that didn't age but their brains did and they had to put their memories on tapes to preserve them. Also no new people could be born.

The main character comes across a boy whose pet dog had died, so he creates a machine so he can get this boy a puppy. He realizes he's the one who created the anti aging machine and wants to turn it off.

Another one was about a judge who lives in a society where the way their court system works is that they shoot at the accused, if they're not guilty a God of some kind will intervene and prevent it. One judge realizes how broken the system is when a lower class girl is put on trial for having sex or something with an upper class boy but the boy isn't facing justice.

Please help, even a name of an author whose work sounds similar. I have been searching for years one of my favorite short story collection when I was a  teenager, but now I can't even remember a title!

Comment: The collection is [*The Unexpected Dimension*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?37727) by Algis Budrys. The stories you described are ["The End of Summer"](https://web.archive.org/web/20010413125446/http://www.tomorrowsf.com/subscribers/stories/summer/end_of_summer.html) and ["The Executioner"](https://web.archive.org/web/20010831005909/http://www.tomorrowsf.com/subscribers/stories/executioner/executioner.html).

Comment: I don't have time to write a real answer. Anyone who wants to answer, be my guest.

Comment: By the way, "The End of Summer" was the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148608/memory-suitcase-story) but this isn't a duplicate question because the OP is looking for the collection.

Comment: Oops, those two stories also appeared in a 1997 collection called [*Entertainment*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?12456), a NESFA trade paperback.

Comment: @Te Rina: Since user14111 doesn't have the time to write a full answer, I suggest you do it yourself and then accept it to finalize the question.

Comment: I'll add my usual CW answer. Since it's CW everyone should feel free to expand upon it as they wish.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I happened to post answer a mere 2 minutes after you, should i delete my answer,let it be or just edit your answer for more details?

Comment: @shanu In a situation like this I usually post a community wiki answer. The idea behind this is that because CW answers don't earn anyone any rep so everyone can edit the answer as community effort. So in your place I would edit the details into my answer, but it isn't something I feel strongly about.

Answer (score 11):

As identified [by user14111 in a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275634/short-story-collection-featuring-people-who-dont-age-except-their-brains-and-an#comment760086_275634), the collection is probably [The Unexpected Dimension](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?37727) by Algis Budrys.

The two stories you remember are [The End of Summer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55848) and [The Executioner](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55744).

[The End of Summer](https://web.archive.org/web/20010413125446/http://www.tomorrowsf.com/subscribers/stories/summer/end_of_summer.html) is available online here and [The Executioner](https://web.archive.org/web/20010831005909/http://www.tomorrowsf.com/subscribers/stories/executioner/executioner.html) is available here.

Answer (score 6):

It is most likely [The Unexpected Dimensions](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?37727) by [Algis Buldryis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwis_uGC5f7-AhWQbmwGHbFjBNgQFnoECCYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAlgis_Budrys&usg=AOvVaw3uQWMX3YiKTxxLVX8TSDPC).  The stories you described are specifically "[The End of Summer](https://web.archive.org/web/20010413125446/http://www.tomorrowsf.com/subscribers/stories/summer/end_of_summer.html)  and [The Executioner](https://web.archive.org/web/20010831005909/http://www.tomorrowsf.com/subscribers/stories/executioner/executioner.html).

The End of Summer dog dying part -

> He tried to snap the car out of the way, his face suddenly white, but the dog moved unpredictably, its abrupt yell of pain louder than the scream of Fay's brakes. He felt the soft bump, and then his foot jerked away from the clutch and the car stalled convulsively. Even with his engine dead and the car still, he heard no further sound from the dog.

Unjust trial part of The Executioner -

> Blanding paused for another breath. "We, the People of Sovereign New York, accuse Clarissa Jones of attempting to usurp a place not her own; of deliberately and maliciously using the wiles of her sex to claim recognition from a member of a family, said family member being of minor age and hereinafter designated as "John Doe." We further accuse Clarissa Jones, People's woman, of fomenting anarchy--"